# Bound for tail probability

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $\{X_k\}$ is a sequence of r.v.s. s.t. $X_k\rightarrow0$ in probability. Can we bound $\mathbb{P}\{|X_k |>k\epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ without any restriction on $X$'s?

Thank's!

Comment: Look at the Chebyshev inequality maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $p_j(\varepsilon):= \mathbb{P}\{|X_j |>j\epsilon\}$; since $j\geqslant 1$, the inequality $p_j(\varepsilon)\leqslant \mathbb{P}\{|X_j |>\epsilon\}$ holds, hence $p_j(\varepsilon)\to 0$.

Define $X_j:=j^2\mathbf 1(A_j)$, where $(A_j)_{j\geqslant  1}$ is sequence  of measurable sets such that $\mathbb P(A_j)\to 0$. Then $X_j\to 0$ in probability, but for each positive $\varepsilon$, we have for $j\gt 1/\varepsilon$, 
$$A_j\subset\{X_j\gt j\varepsilon\},$$
hence the decay of the sequence $\left(p_j(\varepsilon)\right)_{j\geqslant 1} $ is slower than that of the sequence $\left(\mathbb P(A_j)\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$.